# What is the expectation of number of words 'ab'

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the expectation of number of words 'ab'  in random 20 length phrase that use letters from $\left \{ a,b \right \}$?

There are $2^{20}$ words with length 20 over an alphabet with 2 letters...

Answer (score 4):

There are $19$ places in a $20$-letter phrase where "ab" could occur. In a random phrase, each place has probability $1/4$ of actually having an "ab" there. Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{19}$ be the indicator rvs for the events that "ab" occurs in the various positions. What is sought is the expectation of $X_1+\cdots+X_{19}$, which, by the linearity of expectations is $$ E[X_1+\cdots+X_{19}]=E[X_1]+\cdots +E[X_{19}] = \frac{19}4=4.75.$$
Note this calculation does not depend on the independence of the random variables $X_i$, which (as was pointed out in a since-deleted comment by DonThousand) are *not* independent.

Answer (score 1):

We generate the words like this:

1. Color the space between consecutive letters blue if the first letter differ from the second letter and red if they are equal. Since there are $19$ spaces, there are $2^{19}$ possibilities.
2. Choose either $a$ or $b$ as the first letter, $2$ possibilities. So in total there are $2^{20}$ words.

Now:

- Which space is blue and which is red is independent, means in total there are as much blue as red
- Total number of blue is the sum of words $ab$ and $ba$. Total number of red is the sum of words $aa$ and $bb$.
- Suppose a word has $x$ $ab$ and $y$ $ba$. We can invert the word i.e. switch all $a$ to $b$ and vice versa, to have $y$ $ab$ and $x$ $ba$. Means there are as many $ab$ as $ba$. Same goes for $aa$ and $bb$.

$E(aa)+E(ab)+E(ba)+E(bb)=4E(ab)=19$

$E(ab)=\frac{19}{4}$

Comment: And what about word ababbb....bbabaa . It has 6 marks , 3 related for ab and 3 related for ba. Let's change first letter for b. bbabbb...bbabaa  - only two marks related to ab.

Comment: Hi there, I reread my answer and seems it is quite confusing. I rewrote the answer, hopefully it is clearer this time.